# Generalisation accuracy in Domain Adaptation

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification, conv-neural-network, domain-adaptation

Usually, in all the Unsupervised Domain Adaptation literature the test accuracy (on the target domain obviously) is calculated on the ***unlabelled target examples*** that the model has already seen during the training (but not the labels). Why can we not take a set of completely unseen target data and calculate the accuracy based on that, as done in any other standard classification problem? Is there any flaw with following such an approach? Looking forward to know more regarding this. Thanks!

Comment: Can you add an example (paper, tutorial, etc..) of this test accuracy?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.06487 - This is just one paper. But any other paper on Semi/Un supervised domain adaptation used accuracy in the manner that I have mentioned.